# Hibernate PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter? What happened?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, illegalargumentexception

I receive this exception when I run the code below to display items that belong to a specific category in the  JTable: 
[image]

```
private void categoryComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
                try {
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        String cat = this.categoryComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Items.class);
//HERE LIES THE PROBLEM BUT I HAVE NO CLUE HOW TO SOLVE IT
        List<Items> itemlist = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("category", cat).ignoreCase()).list();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

            if (dtm.getColumnCount()==0) {
            dtm.addColumn("Name");
            dtm.addColumn("Category");
            dtm.addColumn("Quantity");
            dtm.addColumn("Net Price (per unit)");
            dtm.addColumn("Gross Pice (per unit)");
            dtm.addColumn("Net Price (total)");
            dtm.addColumn("Gross Price (total)");
            }
            Font f = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16);      
            JTableHeader header = itemTable.getTableHeader();
            header.setFont(f);
            itemTable.setRowHeight(25);

            if (getQuantity().isEmpty()) {for (int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++) {
                     dtm.addRow(new Object[]{itemlist.get(i).getName(), itemlist.get(i).getCategory().getName(),"-",itemlist.get(i).getNetPrice(), Math.round((Double.valueOf(itemlist.get(i).getNetPrice())*(1d+itemlist.get(i).getVatRate()/100d))), "-", "-"});
                }

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++) {
                    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{itemlist.get(i).getName(), itemlist.get(i).getCategory().getName(), getQuantity().get(itemlist.get(i).getItemId()).getQuantity(), itemlist.get(i).getNetPrice(), itemlist.get(i).getNetPrice()*(itemlist.get(i).getVatRate()+1), getQuantity().get(itemlist.get(i).getItemId()).getQuantity()*itemlist.get(i).getNetPrice(), itemlist.get(i).getNetPrice()*(itemlist.get(i).getVatRate()+1)*getQuantity().get(itemlist.get(i).getItemId()).getQuantity()});
                }

            }

          this.itemTable.setModel(dtm);} catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage()); 
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also here are my XML mapping classes also:

**Caregories.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Categories" table="CATEGORIES" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="categoryId" type="int">
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="100" />
        </property>
     <set name="items" table="ITEMS" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="classes.Items" />
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Items.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Items" table="ITEMS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="itemId" type="int" column="ITEM_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" length="100"/>
        <property name="netPrice" type="java.lang.Integer" column="NET_PRICE"/>
        <property name="vatRate" type="java.lang.Integer" column="VAT_RATE"/>
        <many-to-one name="category" class="classes.Categories" fetch="select" column="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" lazy="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the entity-relationship diagram of my database
[image]

**Categories.java**

```
package classes;
// Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:50 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.util.Set;

public class Categories  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int categoryId;
     private String name;
     private Set<Items> items;

    public Categories() {
    }

    public Categories(int categoryId, String name, Set<Items> items) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.name = name;
        this.items = items;
    }  


    public int getCategoryId() {
        return this.categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Set<Items> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


}
```

**Items.java**

```
package classes;

public class Items  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int itemId;
     private String name;
     private Integer netPrice;
     private Integer vatRate;
     private Categories category;

    public Items() {
    }

    public Items(int itemId, String name, Integer netPrice, Integer vatRate, Categories category) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.name = name;
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
        this.vatRate = vatRate;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return this.itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getNetPrice() {
        return this.netPrice;
    }

    public void setNetPrice(Integer netPrice) {
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
    }
    public Integer getVatRate() {
        return this.vatRate;
    }

    public void setVatRate(Integer vatRate) {
        this.vatRate = vatRate;
    }

    public Categories getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Categories category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


}
```

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred calling getter of classes.Categories.categoryId  at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4933)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4633)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:276)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:495)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:288)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:2102)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:2071)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2006)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1920)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1999)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:370)   at
>   stock.view.StockView.categoryComboBoxActionPerformed(StockView.java:530)
>     at
>   stock.view.StockView$FormListener.actionPerformed(StockView.java:344)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1264)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1337)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:123)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:94)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:132)
>     at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem(JComboBox.java:716)   at
>   stock.view.StockView.FillUpComboBox(StockView.java:103)   at
>   stock.view.StockView.(StockView.java:41)    at
>   main.view.MainMenu.stockMenuItemActionPerformed(MainMenu.java:290)    at
>   main.view.MainMenu$FormListener.actionPerformed(MainMenu.java:240)    at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an
>   instance of declaring class   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:42)
>     ... 71 more

Comment: Post the Pojo classes.Categories code

Comment: posted as you wished...can the problem stem from the fact that there is a bidirectional association between them?

Comment: criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("category", cat).ignoreCase()) this is wrong. You can compary relationship with a string.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the error though. But you should fix it as a start.

Comment: Also inverse should be true inverse=”true”

Comment: Again I am not sure this is the cause, most probably it is something else. But do the changes and we will see again.

Comment: I see, so then how should I compare them? using toString()?

Answer (score 1):

`criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("category", cat).ignoreCase())` this is wrong. You can't compare relationship with a string. Here is one example coming straight from Hibernate documentation how it should be done:

```
List<Items> itemlist = sess.createCriteria(Items.class)      
    .createAlias("category",c)
        .add( Restrictions.eq("c.name", cat))
    .list();
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Another observation is that you are using inverse = false .  IMO you want it to be inverse=true

Comment: So in my case how would it look like: `List<Items> itemlist = criteria.createAlias("categories", "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", cat)).list();`

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: I get could not resolve property: Categories of: classes.Items QueryException with `List<Items> itemlist = criteria.createCriteria("Categories", "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", cat)).list();`, I got a little bit confused to be honest

Comment: your property name is "category" from what I can see in the code.  You are not copy pasting correctly. See what I have written above.

Comment: List<Items> itemlist = sess.createCriteria(Items.class)      
    .createAlias("category",c)
        .add( Restrictions.eq("c.name", cat))
    .list();

Comment: But then c should be declared as **Categories**, because it asks for a variable c

Comment: private Categories category;
This is your property name. It is category, not categories. You are creating alias for this property.

Comment: I can see that, but actually I have never dealt with aliases...for c NetBeans write a "cannot find symbol error", should I just ignore it?